# Simplifying the output of a Laravel model query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Suppose I run the following and need to know the results in an easy to examine format:

```
$orders = Order::where('status', $value);
```

How would I show something that doesn't display the entire model object, only the records retrieved, when I do `dd($orders)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$orders = Order::where('status', $value)->get();
dd($orders->toArray()); // Outputs only an array of records retrieved from db
```

There is also `toJson()` to convert into `json` string but it's possible to get `json` representation of the data by returning it from the controller/function, for example:

```
return Order::where('status', $value)->get(); // Output will be in json format
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dd`ing, just return the model directly from your route/controller:

```
return Order::where('status', $value)->get();
```

This will automatically convert it to JSON.

For even better inspection, install the [JSON View](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) Chrome extension; it'll format your JSON nicely, and allow you to inspect it beautifully.